# Redirecting / Replacing domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns

i have moved a website from sub.domain-1.com to https://domain-2.com/blog
keeping the post structure same.
I want to redirect everything to second domain
Here is what i did already

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain-1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sub.domain-1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain-2.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This works fine for main domain.
But as i have posts 
sub.domain-1. com/20xx/xx/xx/some-post-or-some-page/ 
I want ALL posts should be redirect to 
https://domain-2.com/blog/20xx/xx/xx/some-post-or-some-page/

Or simply i meant to replace all instances of sub.domain-1. com/ with domain-2.com/blog/

Comment: What is the problem? Those rules look like they should work

Answer (score 0):

In sub.domain-1/htaccess, try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ https://domain-2.com/blog/$1
```